# Angular2 - OnInit accessing functions

Tags: javascript, angular

I keep running into issues with OnInit accessing functions within the same component class.

My basic setup is as follows:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
...
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

login(){...}

ngOnInit() {

    this.login(); //1

    document.onkeypress = function(e){
        if ( document.body === document.activeElement ) {
            this.login(); //2
        }

    };
```

1 will fire the login function on page load as expected, but 2 complains login isn't a function. How do I appropriately access the login function within AppComponent?

Comment: You need to use an arrow function - `document.onkeypress = (e)=> { ... }` - to preserve the lexical scoping of `this`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with scoping.
The time you call `this.login` from the `onkeypress` callback `this` refers to the global object so `this.login` is equal to `window.login` which in your case is undefined

Possible solutions

**Cache `this`**

```
var _this = this;
document.onkeypress = function(e){
    if ( document.body === document.activeElement ) {
        _this.login(); //2
    }

};
```

**Explicitly set context with `.bind`**

```
document.onkeypress = function(e){
    if ( document.body === document.activeElement ) {
        this.login(); //2
    }

}.bind(this);
```

**Use ES6 arrow functions `()=>{}`**

```
document.onkeypress = (e) => {
    if ( document.body === document.activeElement ) {
        this.login(); //2
    }

};
```